# jQuery: Learning to make a Plugin: Basic Accordion Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, accordion

Again thank you to all who spend a little of their time helping me understand jQuery a little more, its very much appreciated.

I'm trying to make an effort and push my jQuery further, slowly. So I have been quite active within stackoverflow to ask questions to problems I'm facing..asking "*why*" a lot.. I'm very comfortable with jQuery and use it on a daily basis. However there is always more to learn and gaps in my knowledge to fill. So I decided to try and make a jQuery plugin - something very simple that I can expand as a personal project so I can learn doing something hands on.

So, I chose to make a very simple **accordion plugin**.
[jsFiddle of the current accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/qDNE8/)

```
(function($){
//The current script for the plugin..
    $.fn.simpleAccordion = function() { 
        $("li a").live("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("li div").slideUp(200);
            $(this).next(':hidden').slideDown(200);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**FIRST PROBLEM:** I've been reading the jQuery docs [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).
The first problem I have come across, in the documents is states $(this) is commonly used incorrectly.. and should be **"this.fadeIn('normal', function(){..."** -

```
 $(this).next(':hidden').slideDown(200);
```

Am I using "this" in the right context within the line above?
At present I understand that "this" is referencing the selector the plugin was invoked on.. so ul#accordion.. then why doesnt it work without $("")..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#accordion").simpleAccordion();
});
```

**THE SECOND PROBLEM:** 
***I think I found a solution to this myself (see below)***
I was testing what I have already and realised if I put an ancor tag/link in the content body of my accordion, this link will also open and close the panels.. I tried to change the selector to the click function to

```
$("li a:first-child").live("click",..
```

to make sure only the first ancor tag proceeding the link that was clicked had an event attached.. but no luck...I do not want every single a tag within an li to fire off the slide functions I want them left alone.. so would it be best giving the a class name or using a much more specific selector? :P

I think I found the correct solution to the second question (below)

```
$("li > a:first-of-type").live("click", function(e){
```

Thanks again, I know this was a little wordy!

[jsFiddle of the current accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/qDNE8/)

Comment: although there are different styles for creating plugins, will gain a lot by analyzing other plugin code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first question:
this in the context of an event-callback is always the element that has triggered the event.
To use all the jQuery magic, this element hast to be extended by $(this). Only then it is a jQuery-Object.
In your plugin you should not use `$("li div")` because that will give you all divs in an li on your complete page. You want only those within the current context.
So use `$(this)` and then parents(), find() etc to go up or down in the DOM.

On your plugin:
Read on in the Plugin-Tutorial. You have to change your code to make it a real plugin. At this state you are breaking the chain.
something like `$('.element).simpleAccordion().data('foo','bar')` won't work because you don't return the object again.

And: don't use `live()` which is deprecated. have a look at `.on()` in the docs.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

hope that helps

Comment: I think you may have helped more than you know.. I was just trying to add some options but the default were not getting over written, but your saying this is because im not returning anything?

Comment: sorry to ask another question..

I did a little test and added a <ul><li><div>test</div></li></ul> to my page and you were correct this did close, argh.

but when I tried using $(this) only the "the thing" I click on closes..

very confused.

Comment: see this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability on how to chain   and this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods (2nd code-block) for a best-practice-template for jQuery-Plugins.

Comment: for your next question: you need to do something like: `$(this).closest('ul').find('li div').slideUp();`  (for the current element : get the next parent that is a UL, find all div's in an li, close them)

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to walk you through this a bit.

First, when you do this:

```
$.fn.foo = function () {
    // some code
}
```

This let you do this:

```
$('div').foo();
```

The clincher here is that, inside `foo`, the `this` variable would be equivalent to the selection the function was acting on. In this case,

```
this === $('div')
```

Therefore, I don't see the point of **selecting a completely different selection inside your plugin function** (i.e. `$('li a')`).

You probably mean it like this:

```
$.fn.simpleAccordion = function () {
    var stuff = this.find('li a');
    // use your stuff
    return this; // for chaining
};
```

Secondly (and completely out of the question context), stop using `.live()`. Not only does it not make sense (you're making your plugin function act on something that looks like it should already be existing), it's arguably bad practice. Use `.on()` instead, or if you're using jQuery pre-1.7, `.delegate()`. But make sure first that it's not `.bind()` you really want (which I highly suspect).

To answer your second question, it's really a little vague. But from experience, there's almost always a way to select (and therefore modify / use) HTML elements in your DOM **without having to flag them with decorator classes** much like you'd use to identify / mark them.

If `:first-child` is firing off animations on more elements than you would've wanted, I suspect that you're either using the wrong selector/s, or you're not confining your jQuery method calls enough (like if you're misusing `this`, or selecting **again** inside a plugin function -- see point 1 above).

Without HTML markup, I can't point you to what you should improve though.

I don't know how much it can help you, but I wrote a really quick article on plugin authoring some time before. [You might want to take a look](http://richardneililagan.com/2011/08/how-to-write-a-jquery-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you for your comments much appreciated, I'll read the article.

Comment: @Richard Neil Ilagan   bind() uses on() in jQuery core now

Comment: @charlietfl ~ I know. I use `on()` all the time, but refer to the two flavors as `bind` and `delegate` accordingly. Kind of difficult to differentiate the two classes of usage otherwise.